# java- reset list iterator to first element of the list

Tags: java, iterator

I need to know how to "reset" LinkedList iterator to its first element.

For example:

```
LinkedList<String> list;
Iterator iter=list.listIterator;
iter.next();
iter.next();
```

Over and over again and after many moves of the iterator, I need to "reset" the position of the iterator.

I want to ask how I can "reset" my iterator to the first element.

I know that I can get list iterator of the first element in this way:

```
iter= list.listIterator(1);
```

Is this the best solution? Or maybe I missed something in Oracle docs?

Comment: Why not create a new iterator?

Comment: well you've missed something, if you need to do more than next and maybe previous, iterator is not the best choice. Why do you need to reset?

Comment: I trying to understand the idea of dynamic list in java. A few weeks ago I have a problem with session variable on jsp oage. From EL and taglibs I can use a method of iterator but I cant redefine it (I still have poor knowledge about jsp but I still improving it :)) What do You mind when You wrote "iterator is not the best choice" ? Could You explain it to me? :)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Best would be not using `LinkedList` at all, usually it is slower in all disciplines, and less handy. (When mainly inserting/deleting to the front, especially for big arrays LinkedList is faster)

Use `ArrayList`, and iterate with

```
int len = list.size();
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  Element ele = list.get(i);
}
```

Reset is trivial, just loop again.
If you insist on using an iterator,  then you have to use a new iterator:

```
iter = list.listIterator();
```

(I saw only once in my life an advantage of LinkedList: i could loop through whith a while loop and remove the first element)

Comment: when deleting and inserting mainly to front then LinkedList is faster.

Comment: Even removing items from the middle is faster in case of LinkedList. That is if you are iterating through and removing items with iterator.remove(). ArrayList would necessitate shifting of the remaining items.

Comment: @Sohaib, yes mainly it depends on the size of the list. Up to a specific number of elements System.arraycopy, which internal uses C - memcopy  , which is used to shift the array is faster. Advanced implementation switch the underlying implementation depoending on element size.

Answer (score 66):

You can call `listIterator` method again to get an instance of iterator pointing at beginning of list:

```
iter = list.listIterator();
```

Comment: awesome. it's not immediately obvious that this call doesn't just return the same reference to the iterator that you're already using. But I guess looking into the source would've solved that answer as well. Here's a link for anyone curious as this is a habit I'm trying to be better about: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.listIterator%28%29

Answer (score 13):

This is an alternative solution, but one could argue it doesn't add enough value to make it worth it:

```
import com.google.common.collect.Iterables;
...
Iterator<String> iter = Iterables.cycle(list).iterator();
if(iter.hasNext()) {
    str = iter.next();
}
```

Calling hasNext() will reset the iterator cursor to the beginning if it's a the end.

Comment: That sounds like a quirk you discovered rather than something guaranteed by the interface.

Comment: "Returns an iterable whose iterators cycle indefinitely over the elements of iterable"
https://guava.dev/releases/20.0-rc1/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#cycle-java.lang.Iterable-

Answer (score 6):

What you may actually want to use is an `Iterable` that can return a fresh `Iterator` multiple times by calling `iterator()`.

```
//A function that needs to iterate multiple times can be given one Iterable:
public void func(Iterable<Type> ible) {
    Iterator<Type> it = ible.iterator(); //Gets an iterator
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        it.next();
    }
    it = ible.iterator(); //Gets a NEW iterator, also from the beginning
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        it.next();
    }
}
```

You must define what the `iterator()` method does just once beforehand:

```
void main() {
    LinkedList<String> list; //This could be any type of object that has an iterator
    //Define an Iterable that knows how to retrieve a fresh iterator
    Iterable<Type> ible = new Iterable<Type>() {
        @Override
        public Iterator<Type> iterator() {
            return list.listIterator(); //Define how to get a fresh iterator from any object
        }
    };
    //Now with a single instance of an Iterable,
    func(ible); //you can iterate through it multiple times.
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If the order doesn't matter, we can re-iterate **backward** with the same iterator using the `hasPrevious()` and `previous()` methods:

```java
ListIterator<T> lit = myList.listIterator(); // create just one iterator
```

Initially the iterator sits at the beginning, we do *forward* iteration:

```java
while (lit.hasNext()) process(lit.next()); // begin -> end
```

Then the iterator sits at the end, we can do **backward** iteration:

```java
while (lit.hasPrevious()) process2(lit.previous()); // end -> begin
```

Comment: Hmm @ryenus...I like your idea to iterate backwards from the last element using **hasPrevious()** and **previous()** after the 'forward' iteration has occurred. That seems like a perfect solution if you need to use the same iterator instance (not sure why you'd actually need need to use the same instance over and over though). I am curious if looping back to the start of the iteration is less expensive than creating a new iterator instance, but I guess that would also be somewhat dependent on the size of the list.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `iterator()` on a Collection impl, probably would get a new Iterator on each call.

Thus, you can simply call `iterator()` again to get a new one.

---

### Code

**IteratorLearn.java**

```
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;

/**
 * Iterator learn.
 *
 * @author eric
 * @date 12/30/18 4:03 PM
 */
public class IteratorLearn {
    @Test
    public void test() {
        Collection<Integer> c = new HashSet<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            c.add(i);
        }

        Iterator it;

        // iterate,
        it = c.iterator();
        System.out.println("\niterate:");
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            System.out.printf("\t%d\n", it.next());
        }
        Assert.assertFalse(it.hasNext());

        // consume,
        it = c.iterator();
        System.out.println("\nconsume elements:");
        it.forEachRemaining(ele -> System.out.printf("\t%d\n", ele));
        Assert.assertFalse(it.hasNext());
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
iterate:
    0
    1
    2
    3
    4
    5
    6
    7
    8
    9

consume elements:
    0
    1
    2
    3
    4
    5
    6
    7
    8
    9
```

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is, set the iterator to the first position mannualy with a while loop.

```
while(iter.hasPrevious())
{
    iter.previous();
}
```

when you get out of the loop you will have your iterator at the position 0

###### sorry any grammar mistakes

Answer (score 0):

Well some of the version of java does not have a reset method for the iterator, so we are required to use the multiple iterator for number of use cases, which ultimately increases the memory consumption.

so it's simple way to use the same iterator again if needed by declaring a global function and pass the collection as argument.

for eg.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/459UL.jpg)

for eg (Written program)
package com.javalearn;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class Java_Learn {

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            list.add("Hello");
            list.add("World");
            list.add("It's");
            list.add("me.");

            iter(list);

            System.out.println(list.size());
            System.out.println(list.indexOf("me."));
            System.out.println(list.remove(3));

            iter(list);
    }
    static void iter(ArrayList<String> arr){
            Iterator itr = arr.iterator();
            while(itr.hasNext()){
                    System.out.println(itr.next());
            }
    }
```

}